# OCP-QT Wallet (Based on Bitcoin QT) Cannot fnd Locales 'qrc_bitcoin.cpp'

Tags: compiling, bitcoin-qt-setup

I a trying to Compile an Altcoin wallet that has been Forked off Bitcoin but i am getting this error when i try to compile:

```
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/rcc -name bitcoin src/qt/bitcoin.qrc -o qrc_bitcoin.cpp
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_ar.qm'
Makefile:1007: recipe for target 'qrc_bitcoin.cpp' failed
make: *** [qrc_bitcoin.cpp] Error 1
```

I have tried searching for answers to this question but I found none, Does someone know how to fix that Problem?

Comment: I think you don't have all file, look this [directory](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/qt/locale), you have all this file?